# Whats a better solution for Web Automation - Geckofx or WebBrowser Control in .NET

Tags: c#, geckofx

Iam coding a solution for web automation, I have been using the default web browser control in some of my past projects. However I have found that the performance of web browser control is not very good.

After running for some time it usually hangs the application and also sometimes leads to memory leaks if the application is executed for long.

I want to know if someone here has used Gecko - http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/ and whats its performance for doing long web scraping tasks. My application is in C#.

Comment: Ok I have started programming using Gecko, I will keep this question posted so that other's can get benefited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the web browser control, but haven't used GeckoFX.  Having said, that, the project description for GeckoFX specifically mentions the class model for exposing the HTML DOM.  This  leads me to believe that the GeckoFX control may be better suited to automation.  The web browser control's support for the DOM is not very robust.

Comment: Yeah the class support for DOM is very programmer friendly in GeckoFX.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something more lightweight, try SimpleBrowser for .Net - open sourced at Github.

https://github.com/axefrog/SimpleBrowser